# What is the best Responsive slider and easy to customize

Tags: jquery, css

any one know , what is the best and easy to customize responsive slider.

Thank You

Comment: By slider, do you mean a slider component or an Image Slider?

Comment: yes , image slider for website header :)

Comment: Nivo Slider....and your question is off-topic

Comment: This is an opinion question an should be closed. "best" is a relative term based on a user's needs and a programmer's ability.

Try reformatting the question into a non-opinion based question.

Comment: http://flexslider.woothemes.com

Comment: @Phlume well, rather than opinion based, this question is off topic as it is asking us to recommend a tool/script etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This one is also good. I've used it before, and it's easy to customize. Also please check it out [Flexsilder](http://flexslider.woothemes.com/)

Answer (score 1):

Check [BXSLIDER](http://bxslider.com/). it provides options to be responsive

Comment: i think it not working on ie8

Answer (score 1):

I'd go with Bootstrap's carousel. It's very easy to learn and use.